# Web Assembly: passing memory address between Rust script and JavaScript host

Tags: rust, webassembly

I'm trying to run a Rust code, compiled via `cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release` inside of Web Assembly module that runs in JavaScript host process. The code generally is meant to test passing string/binary content between WASM module and host.

My Rust code is basically a buffered `Read` trait - Rust code defines a fixed size buffer and calls external function that is supposed to fill it and return number of bytes received this way:

```rust
extern "C" {
    fn read(ptr: *mut u8, len: u32) -> u32;
}

// here I'm using a static buffer but it could be also dynamically
// allocated
const BUF_LEN: usize = 4;
static mut BUF: [u8; BUF_LEN] = [0u8; BUF_LEN];

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern "C" fn parse() -> f64 {
    let mut result = String::new();
    while {
        let ptr = BUF.as_mut_ptr();
        let n = read(ptr, BUF_LEN as u32) as usize;
        result.push_str(std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&BUF[0..n]));
        n == BUF_LEN
    } { }
    
    result.parse().unwrap()
}
```

Then in JavaScript code I'm defining a queue of values to be passed into that `read` function. Since value itself may be longer than provided buffer, I'm passing it in parts if necessary.

```js
const module = new WebAssembly.Module(bin)
const memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({initial: 2}) // size in pages

let bytes = new Uint8Array([])
const messages = [
    "123.4",
    "1234256.6"
]
const importObject = {
    imports: { memory },
    env: {
        read(ptr, len) {
            if (bytes.byteLength === 0) {
                // start of new message
                const encoder = new TextEncoder()
                const value = messages.pop()
                bytes = encoder.encode(value)
            }
            let written = (bytes.byteLength > len) ? len : bytes.byteLength
            bytes = bytes.slice(0, written)
            ///FIXME: ptr doesn't point into available memory.buffer
            const view = new Uint8Array(memory.buffer, ptr, written)
            view.set(bytes)
            return written
        }
    }
}
const instance = new WebAssembly.Instance(module, importObject)
const { parse } = instance.exports
console.log(parse())
console.log(parse())
```

My issue here is that pointer passed from Rust via extern `read(ptr: *mut u8, len: u32) -> u32` to JavaScript doesn't point to a WASM memory buffer object. Is there some sort of mapping necessary in there? I thought that pointers are mapped onto offset addresses inside of WASM memory yet it doesn't seem true.

Comment: I'm not sure that is how WASM memory is intented to be used. Try using `instance.exports.memory` instead of creating your own.